# The mat-datepicker UI stopped working properly

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular-cdk, mat-datepicker

Suddenly mat-datepicker stopped working properly. The UI is broken. 
I tried to update @angular/material and @angular/cdk no success though.

[image]

template

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>{{ 'DEFAULT.INITIAL' | translate }}</label>
   <input class="form-control " type="text" [matDatepicker]="dateStart" (click)="openCalendar('dateStart')" formControlName="dateStart">

   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateStart"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #dateStart></mat-datepicker>
</div>
```

Any ideia why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It was css.

Comment: where in your CSS? I have the same issue

Comment: I don't have access to the project anymore. Can you recreate your project on stackblitz, so I can help you?